# SOA and APIs - are the APIs endpoint services or they require a distinct service?

Tags: ruby, web-services, api, rest, soa

I'm designing a RESTful Service Oriented Architecture web application to make it scale as good as possible and put different kind of services on different machines (separating resource intensive operations from other services).

I also want users to be able to access their data to make their own applications.
I'm not sure if I have to design these services to be opened to the world, so it's just a matter of make them listen on a web domain (like AWS) or create another service to handle API requests.

It makes sense to me to have secure opened webservices, but it does add a lot of complexity to the architecture itself because each service becomes a client that has to be recognized (trust) by other services in the same suite, just as well as I have to recognize 3rd party applications trying to access their own data.

Is this a right SOA approach? What I want to be sure is that I'm not mixing wrong concepts designing a wrong service oriented architecture.

All services have crud interfaces so they could be queried using REST principles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the nature of your system, it may be viable to have unsecured webservices, so they can all talk to each other without the security overheads. To make the services available to 3rd parties, you could then use a [Service Perimeter Guard](http://soapatterns.org/service_perimeter_guard.php) as the only mechanism for accessing the services externally and apply security at this layer. This has the benefit of providing consistent security across all of your services, however if the perimeter is compromised then access to all of the services is obtained.

This approach may not be viable for all services. For instance information that is considered "personal-in-confidence" (e.g., employee data such as home addresses, emergency contact details, health data, etc), will need to be secured so that unauthorised staff cannot access it.

Regarding your comment of putting different services on different machines, this will result in under-utilised resources on some machines and possibly over-utilised resources on others. To avoid this, deploy all services to all machines and use a load-balancer. This will provide more optimal resource usage and simplify deployments (e.g., using Chef or Puppet) as all of the nodes are the same. As the resource usage increases, you can then simply add more nodes. Similarly if the resource usage is low, you can remove nodes.

Regarding your last sentence, there is a whole lot more to REST than CRUD (such as HATEOAS).

Comment: Thanks for the rich answer! I'm going to read about the Service Perimeter Guard. Since all data has to be considered sensitive because regards our customers and I want to keep the suite consistent I think at the end I'll implement a solution very similiar to OAuth1 (signature), so that services can also work on HTTP (because there's no permanent token to generate multiple request). I'm trying to follow the most strict rules about SOA to avoid any point of failure (each service must distrust any request before authentication), I'd like to avoid new teammates to be able to mess up everything.

Comment: I also like very much the thought about machines utilization, but wouldn't it be more useful to have optimized environments depending on the kind of service instead of reply the same environment on multiple machines? Example: put high-write services on a ramfs machine, put cpu-intensive services on a multiple-cpu machine... and so on. It should allow me to optimize resources (including costs) because I should not buy all servers with high hardware specs, don't you think? (just to clarify your concept)

Comment: In high performance situations it can make sense (cost wise) to move some services to specific nodes, however you need to weigh up the cost benefit, compared to the extra management and deployment overheads (which = increased costs for those activities). It is not something you would do "just in case", it would be something you would do to improve the performance of a particular set of services, once they have been shown to be under-performing and the actually bottle-neck is know. More common is to separate your OLTP services from your OLAP services, so OLAP queries don't impact OLTP requests.